# Load html URL (Flash Video) to specific size of Webview Android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to load html url that contains flash video to specific size of webview. I mean I have one LinearLayout that will vary with different resoultion screen. And that layout contains Webview with "MATCH_PARENT" width and height. But It is not able to load url that can be fit to that layout.

My XML layout looks like below image :

[image]

My Code :

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.id_webview);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });

   mWebView.loadUrl("http://XXXXXXXXXX/XX/XX.html");
```

So here It is not able to load webview properly that can be fit to this yellow part of layout. Sometimes it is loading half of yellow part or sometimes quarter of yellow part. So Its vary depends on different resolutions of screens. But I wanna load that webview perfectly fit to that layout even if that layout vary or not.

**Update:**

I'm able to load flash content perfectly with whole width of screen.So If I will remove red part of Layout , I'm able to see flash perfectly with webview. But If I add something left side, flash is cutting by the same percent of left layout from the right margin. So webview is able to load whole page but not able to load whole flash contains with that whole page.

Let me take your help or best suggestion if I'm doing something wrong over here.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Any solution found?

Comment: @user1444172 : nope,After few much days, I got that there is problem with version above 4.1 because android has no more support about flash in webview, they supports HTML5. So if possible convert it into HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this problem requires modifying HTML and CSS, not android layout code. The WebView is just like a web browser. Therefore, we can rephrase your question as: how do I design a web page so that the video fills the entire page?

You will have to mess around with the HTML page until the flash panel's parameters are correct. A good starting point: here is the css needed to make an image fill a WebView

```
.video
{
  width: 100%;
}
```

See [example that uses the width attribute to make a full width image](http://jsfiddle.net/UDW72/2/).

Comment: Hello dude, Thanks for your reply. Actually I know this solution but I dont have access on that HTML or CSS. So I wanna achieve this from android side only!!

Comment: Even If I'm going to open that URL with any browser on desktop, I'm able to seen it in full view.So may be it is already defined as 100% width

Comment: I have checked again. It looks like full size with all browsers of different resolutions desktop. So I think what you are saying it is already there. Can we say by checking this way ? M I right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [WebView.setInitialScale](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setInitialScale%28int%29) ? And you may also need to calculate the specific value (used as the input param) for devices with different resolutions.

Actually WebView's width is decided by the page content itself so `MATCH_PARENT` helps little. So changing the initial scale is something like changing the zooming level, this way the web page "looks" fit into its parent layout.

Comment: 1. Please also take a look if the URL you loaded into WebView is a mobile version, by that I mean you if that page contains the `viewport` meta with some attributes like `width=device-width` in it. That's why your page or i.e. your flash video is always with fixed width (= device width).  2. And you may want to read this section [**`Specifying Viewport Properties`**](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html) to see if it helps.

Comment: Yup exactly, I have tried to remove that tag also. It doesn't help. can you just tried to create sample project from your side? I can give you flash URL.